# Prove that the function given by series is differentiable II.

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{n(n+2)}$ is a $C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$-function?

I can't use Weierstrass test. I don't see, how to use Dirichlet and Abel theorem for uniform convergence of function series for this function. I think that I should prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{n(n+2)}$ is uniformly convergent series, but how to do this?

Please, help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint :}$

Prove that :

$ \bullet $ The $ f_{n} $'s are $ \mathcal{C}^{1} $ functions on $ \mathbb{R} \cdot $

$ \bullet $ $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{f_{n}'} $ converges uniformly on any segment of $ \mathbb{R} \cdot $

$ \bullet $ There exists some $ x_{0}\in\mathbb{R} $, such that $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)} $ converges.

Then you can conclude that $ f=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{f_{n}}\in\mathcal{C}^{1}\left(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\right) $, and that $ \left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ f'\left(x\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{f_{n}'\left(x\right)} \cdot $

Comment: Thank you for Your answer. I didn't note that differentiability of the function is a local property. From this theorem I had a differentiable function on any interval $[a,b]$, but I still look for differentiability for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Should I write here my solution of this problem if I don't have any problem with it?

Comment: @mbiola feel free to share your work with us.